# Jemeter HTML report is not getting generated using Java code

Tags: java, jmeter

I am executing a JMX file and trying to create a HTML dashboard report for the same but only .jtl file is getting created ,HTML Dashboard file is not getting created .I am getting the error :
org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.GenerationException: Class name "org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.JsonExporter" is not valid.
I tried Below Code :

```html
  public static void generateReport(String reportName,ExtentTest testReporter) {
        try {
            
            JMeterUtils.setProperty("jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.property.output_dir", reportDirectory + reportName);
            JMeterUtils.setProperty("org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.JMETER_REPORT_OUTPUT_DIR_PROPERTY", reportDirectory + reportName+"Test");
            String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
            if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
                summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
            }
            File report = new File(reportDirectory + reportName + "_JTL_Results");
            File reportFile = new File(reportDirectory + reportName + "_JTL_Results" + "\\result.jtl");
            if (report.exists()) {
                flushDirectory(report);
                LOG.info("Report folder deleted");
                if (reportFile.exists()) {
                    boolean delete1 = reportFile.delete();
                    LOG.info("Report File deleted" + delete1);
                }
            }
            ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
            reportGenerator = new ReportGenerator(reportFile.getPath(), logger);
            logger.setFilename(reportFile.getPath());
            testplanTree.add(testplanTree.getArray()[0], logger);
            jMeterEngine.configure(testplanTree);
            print_util.ts_info(testReporter, "Performance Execution Started..........");
            print_util.ts_passed(testReporter, "Performance Execution Started..........");
           
            jMeterEngine.run();
            reportGenerator.generate();
            print_util.ts_info(testReporter, "Report Generated Successfully");
            print_util.ts_passed(testReporter, "Report Generated Successfully");
           
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            print_util.ts_info(testReporter, e.toString());
            print_util.ts_failed_ss(testReporter,
                    "Report is not generated", VNSPPage.driver);
            org.testng.Assert.fail("Report is not generated");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have space(s) in reportDirectory or reportName?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get HTML reporting dashboard generated you need to have the following [properties](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#reporting) defined:

```
JMeterUtils.setProperty("jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.classname", "org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.HtmlTemplateExporter");
JMeterUtils.setProperty("jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.property.output_dir","report-output/dashboard");
```

With regards to `org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.JsonExporter` class problem - it should be present in [ApacheJMeter_core.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_core) so make sure to have this file in your [project classpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html). Also make sure that all JMeter dependencies have the same version.

More information:

- [Generating Report Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)
- [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)
- [jmeter-from-code example project](https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code/src/master/)